# while clone a maven multimodule project from git into intellij the source, test source and resource roots are not set automatically

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

while clone a maven multimodule project from git into IntelliJ the source, test source, and resource roots are not set automatically. If I am setting those things then the project is not working. Please help me with this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snice.png)
after adding SDK, If i am not setting the content root then no error but the I am not able to start the project. If I set the content root it gives the following error.
[after adding SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRLqa.png)

Comment: any screenshot or log will be more helpful

Comment: I am not able to see the run option in main class and no run or debug option is ther in the test classes.

Comment: paste screenshot... looks it didn't imported properly...

Comment: If I am setting source root and all then there are lots of error for dependency are showing.

Comment: Maven given error if unstructured. If it is multimodule project, remove it from intellij, go to physical directory remove .classpath and target folder. Re-import them. On the top right click on Project and try to update Maven on current project

Comment: I tried reimporting also but it is not working

Comment: It is clearly mentioned you don't have JDK linked in your Intellij add that first https://guides.codepath.com/android/setting-up-intellij-idea

Comment: I have added the SDK also but it is also not resolved the problem.

Comment: remove target(all module) folder try to build your project now... mvn clean install. There must be order defined in parent pom

Comment: Never define an order in the pom file. Use dependencies to automatically let Maven handle the order.

Comment: Have you tried to run reimport from Maven tool window?